# How to add emoji to a title in HTML

Tags: html, emoji, page-title

I want to make the title of my website start with the flag of my country. However, if I copy the emoji itself or its unicode, it doesn`t work. Copying emojis just brings me the name of it in the title, not the emoji itself.

There is only one question about it on stackoverflow, but it was 9 years ago, so maybe something has changed!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best practice to add an icon to the title is to use a favicon
here is an example

```
<title>your country name</title>
    <link
      rel="shortcut icon"
      href="logo_location/pakistan.svg"
      type="image/x-icon"
    />
```

in full usage

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Pakistan</title>
    <link
      rel="shortcut icon"
      href="logo_location/pakistan.svg"
      type="image/x-icon"
    />
  </head>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked much better than emoji!

Answer (score 2):

Go to this site: https://emojipedia.org/emoji/

Grab the codepoint for the emoji you want (ex.U+1F600 for grinning face)

Replace "U+" with "&#x" so it will now look like &#x1F600

Throw that into a html tag

Title will now have a 😀 face

Answer (score 1):

Just added as normal. Check the [current](https://emojipedia.org/) support.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Title with emoji </title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1> My body title  </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ive also copied it from there.
It adds like this 
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Title</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Comment: But that doesn`t work properly)

Comment: Check [this](https://emojipedia.org/flag-ukraine/) page, and check the title. You can check in the console by typing `document.title`

Answer (score 1):

Simply copy and paste an emoji from emojipedia and paste it into , you might be copy and pasting from a different website.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>️</title>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: This is what worked for me ... and the trick is the first line `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Answer (score 0):

Emojis are not really recognized well in html. You could try using an image next to your title using  and just setting it to a really small size.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="icon" href="data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 viewBox=%220 0 100 100%22><text y=%22.9em%22 font-size=%2290%22></text></svg>">
```

[Demo](https://000458870.codepen.website/)

[Source](https://x.com/LeaVerou/status/1241619866475474946?s=20)